# Black screen after plymouth at ubuntu 14.04

Tags: boot, grub2, plymouth

Recently my Ubuntu 14.04  LTS stopped going further than plymouth.

It goes like this:

- Process BIOS
- process grub menu ( I choose 1st option called Ubuntu)
- black screen for couple of seconds
- plymouth screen
- black screen for long time (2 min)
- I terminate process

Does anyone have an idea how to solve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

FYI I solved this problem by
1. In grub menu I entered to advaced oprions
2. I opened root shell command 
3. logged in as root
4. used `sudo mount -o remount,rw /`
5. used `sudo apt-get install --reinstall ubuntu-desktop`

That helped